# Python Twitter bot with Tweepy: mentions_timeline() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to code a bot for Twitter using Tweepy, and I get this error: `mentions_timeline() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` with this line:

`mentions = api.mentions_timeline(last_seen_id, tweet_mode = 'extended')`

I can't take away the `last_seen_id`, so I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed the `since_id` parameter for [`API.mentions_timeline`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.1/api.html#tweepy.API.mentions_timeline) to be a keyword-only argument.

Comment: Oh I didn't know, thank you so much for telling me that. I was already getting crazy with this xd. I don't really get what argument I should write in this new version, what is it, if you could tell me?

Comment: You can just pass it as the keyword argument, `since_id`.

Comment: I get it, thank you so much!

Comment: You should [mark an answer as accepted rather than comment to say "thank you"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Version related issue!

Uninstall the current version of tweepy and then install version 3.7 so you can continue with the exact same process.

```
pip uninstall tweepy
pip install tweepy==3.7
```

The recent tweepy includes some parameter changes.